# KVM/QEMU Virtualizing Existing Linux From Another Partition

Tags: linux, arch-linux, qemu, linux-kvm

I have two arch installations: one is on /dev/nvme0n1p2 (this holds both the root and home directories) with its EFI on /dev/nvme0n1p1 (different partition on same physical disk).

Another arch installation is on another physical drive /dev/sda2 (this holds both the root and home directories) and EFI on /dev/sda1 (another partition on same /dev/sda device).

Both have KDE plasma as the default desktop manager.

I can do hardware boot into any of these two without any problems.

Now I want to start the /dev/sda2 archlinux as VM from while logged into /dev/nvme0n1p2 using KVM/QEMU.

I have done the following:

- Enabled virtualization from BIOS: lscpu | grep Virtualization shows VT-x
- Installed the following packages qemu virt-manager ovmf bridge-utils vde2
- started the moduleskvm, kvm_intel, virtio, virtio_net, virtio_blk, virtio_pci (using modprobe)
- On guest (/dev/sda2): Updated the packages and initramd (mkinitcpio -P)
- Made sure /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 are not mounted (lsblk, fuser, mountpoint)
- Made sure /usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd and /usr/share/edk2/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd exist

Now when I try running the following command:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -enable-kvm \
  -m 4G \
  -cpu host \
  -smp cores=4 \
  -drive file=/dev/sda2,format=raw,index=0,media=disk \
  -drive file=/dev/sda1,format=raw,index=1,media=disk \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd \
  -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd \
  -net nic \
  -net user \
  -vga virtio
```

I get the following error:

```
BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0001 "UEFI QEMU HARDDISK 0100001 " फळ PciRoot (0x0) /Pci (0x1,0x1) /Ata (Pri

mary,Master,0x0) : Not Found

BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0002 "UEFI QEMU HARDDISK 0100002 " from PciRoot (0000) /Pci (0x1,0x1) /Ata (Pri

nary,Slave,0x0) : Not Found

>>Start PXE over 1705. .
```

Could you please help resolve the problem.